# rfkill hard block my wireless when I switch it off/on Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, 17.04

After switch off/on, my Wifi don't work.

```
 # sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:71:cc:41:18:ed
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.10.0-33-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:b0500000-b057ffff memory:b0580000-b058ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
       logical name: enp5s0f1
       version: 14
       serial: c4:54:44:68:ba:8e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 ip=10.0.4.115 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0404000-b0404fff memory:b0400000-b0403fff
```

After restart network-manager I get:

```
sudo rfkill list                      
[sudo] hasło użytkownika maczet:  
0: phy0: Wireless LAN 
       Soft blocked: yes 
       Hard blocked: yes 
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN 
       Soft blocked: yes 
       Hard blocked: no 
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth 
       Soft blocked: no 
       Hard blocked: no 
3: hci0: Bluetooth 
       Soft blocked: no 
       Hard blocked: no
```

How can I turn on my WiFi?
Where can I edit rfkill?

Comment: "hard block" usually means that something is blocking your device physically.  Check if you have a wifi switch or key combo to click that will enable your wifi adapter, as `rfkill` can only resolve soft blocks, not hard blocks, usually/

Comment: Combination of FN+wifi and wifi disable in network-manager resolve problem. I try it few times and wifi works.
Thanks.